# Why PHP MySql connection do not work?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1

I'm using MySQL given from A2Hosting. There I can create users and add them to databases. And i hosted my php codes inside web folder in symfony php structure. I dont want to use any symfony commands or functions. I have my own php calls to DB. But my Php codes gives the following error. But the user names and passwords are correct.

Query failed : Access denied for user `'games_user'@'localhost'` to database `'games'`

Comment: I doubt that in your shared hosting enviornment, if the database is on the same server (localhost) that the database name is "games". It's probably under a different name.  I would check with A2Hosting's control panel for your account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Granting privileges to user 'games_user' could not be enough. You must grant privileges to 'games_user'@'localhost', specifiying the host, even for localhost.

Granting all privileges for instance should look like this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* TO 'games_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Comment: You can executed it from any MySQL client tool, like MySQL command-line or PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: Suggest that you also limit the privileges to `SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE` to avoid any unwanted security problems in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Check permissions for user "games_user" in your "games" database. Access is denied to database "games"